# How to use a sequence expression to return lines from a webstream on demand

Tags: f#

This function is fine, but it doesn't do what I would like it to, but I hav eused it to make sure the use of objects is OK:

```
   let getStreamData_ok (uri:string) =
        let request = WebRequest.Create uri 
        use response = request.GetResponse()
        use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        while not reader.EndOfStream do 
            ignore <| reader.ReadLine()
```

I would like to connect to a stream and pull the file down one line at a time, on demand.  This function doesn't work, I have tried shifting various lines in and out of the sequence expression without any success:

```
let getStreamData_OnDemand (uri:string) =
    let request = WebRequest.Create uri 
    use response = request.GetResponse()

    seq { 
        use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        while not reader.EndOfStream do 
            yield reader.ReadLine() 
    }
```

Usage code:

```
let lines = getStreamData_OnDemand("http://stackoverflow.com/")
for line in lines do
    ignore line
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
let getStreamData_OnDemand (uri:string) = seq {
    let request = WebRequest.Create uri  
    use response = request.GetResponse() 
    use stream = response.GetResponseStream() 
    use reader = new StreamReader(stream) 
    while not reader.EndOfStream do  
        yield reader.ReadLine() }
```

The key difference compared to your second code snippet (the one that uses *sequence expressions*) is that *everything* is done inside a sequence expression. Most importantly, the `use response = ...` line is also enclosed in the sequence expression.

This is essential, because `use` in this case means that the `response` will be disposed only after the iteration over the sequence is completed. In your second code snippet, you would dispose `response` before anything is read from the returned sequence.

In your original snippet, it is disposed after `getStreamData_OnDemand` returns, but that's before you even started iterating over the sequence - so when you start iterating over the sequence, it is already disposed!

Comment: It is working.  Believe it or not I did try this, but the breakpoint in vs 2010 showed each line as NULL - so I assumed it wasn't working.  But I did retry the example after you posted (If Tomas says it will work, I prolly missed something), and it worked - yet still not debugging properly.  But I am ok with that.  Thx

Comment: @akaphenom: Yeah, breakpoints in sequence expressions and computation expressions are still a bit tricky... (There was a _lot_ of improvement since early F# versions, but it is still difficult to debug these)

Comment: Y - I should have had more faith in my code, but I got too preoccupied by the debugger, rather than looking at whether the app was running ok.

Comment: I was just wondering if I understood what you wrote correctly: If I use this approach, will a new connection be opened and then closed for each line I read, or will the same connection be used to read all the lines?

Comment: @cimrg.joe The same connection is kept for all the lines - until you dispose of the enumerator that is used to iterate over them (which happens automatically e.g. when you use the `for` loop).